# How many sprite sheets can I load into an average iPhone/Android?

Tags: android, iphone

I am planning to make a game using the [gideros engine](http://www.giderosmobile.com/) and it looks like I will need about 20 sprite sheets (2048 х 2048) each.

What do you think, would an average iPhone/Android be able to handle it?

Thanks.

Comment: You realize that's 320MB of bitmap data, right?

Comment: I think my pc can easily handle your sprites especially if I'm not surfing the internet on any of the current browsers. (IE6 would be fine)

Comment: no, it's not 320mb ) I tested it and the packed apk is less then 10mb. Takes about 20 seconds to load and works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer:

Quick math:
(note that a Bitmap in high quality in Android takes 4 bytes per pixel)

> > 2048 * 2048 * 20 * 4 = 335,54,320 bytes = 327mb !

So, the answer is: it really depends how this engine uses those sprites:

- If it's a flat-out Bitmap on the dalvik heap, it certainly cannot take it.
- If it's a C++ native code allocating native device memory, it might work but only on high end devices
- If it uses it's own compressed thing and handle those all in native memory allocation, it might work too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to my knowledge, gideros uses C++ native code, so hopefully looks like it might work.

Comment: probably the best option to be sure about it before wasting TOO much time on development it's quickly put a project and ask it to just load the sprites and see how it reacts.

Comment: I tested it, the packed apk is less then 10mb, takes about 20 seconds to load and works fine.

Comment: packed is not a problem because it's for compressed and stored in flash, but usually when the app loads it have to decompress it to the RAM, and that's where problems arise. Apparently the engine is using some compression and stores sprites in the native memory area.